Spring cloud contract wiremock and wiremock standalone - spring boot 3 compatibility
I am working on spring boot 3 migration and currently stuck at spring-cloud-contract-wiremock where the highest version of the library has wiremock-jre8-standalone version with 2.35.2
Should we continue using the same.?
Previously we are using following versions and was not having issues and now i am not even able to get loggers too.
spring-cloud-contract-wiremock:3.1.8
com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standlone:2.27.2
com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.30.1
Kindly suggest me the go to version as the com.github.tomakehurst: wiremock-jre8-standalone is migrated to org.wiremock:wiremock-standalone and should i remove spring-cloud-contract-wiremock?
Thanks for the help in advance..
I have tried upgrading spring-cloud-contract-wiremock to 4.* And adding org.wiremock: wiremock-standalone:3.8.0
But was facing lot of issues..
